# Did I count the limit of this function correctly: $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{x^n-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x-1}{x^{n}-1}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Because you cannot really get the limit with the current given function, I have used L'Hôpitals rule.

$f(x) = x-1$

$f'(x) = 1$

$g(x) = x^n-1$

$g'(x) = nx^{n-1}$

So we got:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{nx^{n-1}} = 0$ for $n>1$

What confuses me much is that I don't know anything about $n$. So can I just do it like that and define $n$ myself?
If it is correct, would it be better if I'd write "for any large n" instead of $n>1$ ?

**Edit: The correct solution is $1/n$, not $0$!**

Comment: You can write $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots +1)$

Comment: There must be something like $n\in\mathbb N$ in the question, otherwise it is poorly worded. Regarding your use of L'Hospital: how do you get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{nx^{n-1}} = 0$ for $n>1$?

Comment: Why zero? Should be $1/n$.

Comment: Thank you guys and girls for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost everything you did (as of the time I write this) is perfectly fine.  The answer is $1/n$, not $0.$  Also, I don't understand what you mean by "define $n$ myself."  You don't need to know anything about $n$ to take the derivative of $x^n-1$, as long as $n$ is a nonzero constant and not another variable (in the sense that $x$ is a variable).

Note also that if $n$ is known to be a positive integer, then you can factor $x^n-1$ to get
$$ x^n - 1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x^2 + x + 1) $$

Then you can cancel the $x-1$ from the numerator and denominator.  And because there are $n$ terms in the second factor on the RHS above, you'll get the same answer of $1/n.$

Comment: You actually do need to know that $n\neq 0$, otherwise you have $x^0-1=1-1=0$ in a place where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you!
To be honest, I don't like the way where you can form $x^{n}-1$ to something else and then continue.
L'Hôspital works as well, right?
I saw my mistake and understood why the solution is $1/n$ now.

Comment: @Hirshy, thanks, updated.

Comment: @berndgr, yes, l'Hôpital is a valid method here.  Just FYI, what you call "form $x^n - 1$ to something else" is just factoring, just like how, for example, $x^2 + 5x + 6$ can be factored into $(x+3)(x+2)$.  Please trust me when I say it's very important that you be comfortable with factoring before you advance much further in your math studies in general.

Comment: @berndgr one can use L'Hospital here, yes. But: L'Hospital is quite a strong result one shouldn't use without care (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366382/why-do-we-need-to-check-for-more-than-frac-infty-infty-or-frac00-w) for an example). What basically happens in tilper's manipulation is just the formula for a (finite) geometric sum which I'd consider to be a very important and standard formula to know.

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{x-1}{x^n-1}=\frac 1{\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}}. $$
Now the denominator is the rate of variation of the function $x^n$ at $x=1$, hence its limit is the derivative $nx^{n-1}$ at $x=1$. So
$$\frac{x-1}{x^n-1}\xrightarrow[x\to 1]{}\frac 1n. $$