# l'Hôpital vs Other Methods

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the first example using repeated l'Hôpital:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{x^4+x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^4)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^4+x^2)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{4x^3}{4x^3+2x} = ... =  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(24x)}{\frac{d}{dx}(24x)} = \frac{24}{24}=1 $$

Consider the following example using a different method:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{x^4+x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{x^4}{x^4}}{\frac{x^4}{x^4}+\frac{x^2}{x^4}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac {1}{1 +\frac{1}{x^2}} = \frac {1}{1+\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty}=0 $$

The graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%20%3D%20(x%5E4)%5C(x%5E4%2Bx%5E2)) clearly tells me the limit should be $0$, but why does l'Hôpital fail?

Comment: These $...$ in the first line is confusing. How many times are you performing L'Hospital Rule in the first case?

Comment: it is a small L before the '

Comment: You also forgot to apply the simplest method: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^4}{x^4+x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=0$ (where you *can't* apply l’Hôpital).

Comment: When you write "..." without being **precise** about what it means (at least in your own head), you ask for trouble.

Comment: Not an answer, but advice. Among the methods for evaluating this kind of limit l'Hopital is likely to be the least informative even when it's correctly used. Looking at the first few terms of the power series expansions helps you understand _why_ the limit is what it is.

Comment: This might be worth reading: [What to check when using L'Hospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366382/why-do-we-need-to-check-for-more-than-frac-infty-infty-or-frac00-w/1366383#1366383)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{x^4+x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^4)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^4+x^2)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{4x^3}{4x^3+2x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{12x^2}{12x^2+2} = \frac{0}{0+2} = 0$$

There. You can't apply l'Hospital there because the denominator doesn't go to $0$.

Answer (score 30):

You haven't checked whether L'Hopital could be applied each time.

Answer (score 14):

After doing derivative one more time you get $12x^2 +2 $ which is not $0$ when $x$ goes to $0$.